# How can I get the signtaure from Vue Signature Pad

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi I am trying to get the signature from the Vue Signature Pad But I can not get the signature I mean the image it says that it's empty

My vuejs code is this one:

```
 const { isEmpty, data } = this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature();
 console.log(isEmpty);
 console.log(data);

 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('signtaure', this.$refs.signaturePad.saveSignature());

 axios.post('/api/employee/update/27141399-8?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    currentObj.success = response.data.success;
 })
```

If I check the console.log() it displays this:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABioAAAJxCAYAAADcoOoFAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7s3c+LrUmaF/AYN25GqkXGndbIbEQYSxQUV+WAi9lIzT8g1S5ddbkQXAhVsxSErlq7qGpcupgqcCHCYNfGhQhjLcQfMM604CC6GAsFR8Fp+eL7jNGnT96b92bmiXif83khOXnvPXki4vNEZla93xMRPzNcBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAIFFAj+zqF3NEiBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgSGoMIkIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBJYJCCqW0WuYAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQEFSYAwQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgMAyAUHFMnoNEyBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAoIKc4AAAQIECBAgQIA

I check the laravel controller to get the file like this:

```
  $request->signature;
```

And it is empty.. a blank value so I wonder how can I send the base_64 image with vuejs to the controller because how I am doing it does not work

Thanks

Comment: Does your config have multipart header? `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}`

Comment: @MichaelMano yes I did